# How can I convert this [['1 0'], ['2 0'], ['3 1 2']] into an adjacency list in python

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, adjacency-matrix

I have a list of the lists that contain strings,
like so :

```
[['1 0'], 
['2 0'], 
['3 1 2']]
```

How can I convert it to an adjacency list in Python please like this: (all ints)

```
{ 
1: 0, 
2:0, 
3: 1,2 
}
```

My attempts so far have gotten me to this:

```
newlist = []
for word in linelist:
    word = word.split(",")
    newlist.append(word)
print(newlist)
```

which produces this:

```
[['1 0'], 
 ['2 0'], 
 ['3 1 2']]
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: If your list of strings is `s`, this comprehension `[{_[0]: _[1:]} for _ in [list(map(int, _[0].split())) for _ in s]]` will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to a dict with something like this:

```py
adj_dict = {}
for inner_list in outer_list:
    values = [int(x) for x in inner_list[0].split()]
    adj_dict[values[0]] = values[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on the data types you want for the values in the dictionary, but this should get you most of the way there:

```
res = {}
for e in a:
    res[e[0][0]] = ','.join(e[0][1::].strip().split(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested comprehension combined with list slices like this:

```py
>>> s = [['1 0'], 
... ['2 0'], 
... ['3 1 2']]
>>> 
>>> [{_[0]: _[1:]} for _ in [list(map(int, _[0].split())) for _ in s]]
[{1: [0]}, {2: [0]}, {3: [1, 2]}]
```

We can also make it a bit shorter, using the `*` operator:

```py
>>> [{_[0]: _[1:]} for _ in [[*map(int, _[0].split())] for _ in s]]
[{1: [0]}, {2: [0]}, {3: [1, 2]}]
```